# how does python locate an imported function

Tags: python

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.abs(x)
```

When running above code, how does python locate the function tf.abs ?
The function is defined in tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py, why it can be referred as tf.abs ？

Comment: This is too general, part of python fundamentals. it is reffered in the tf __init__.py file

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample:
A package foo containing a module bar.py exposing a function bat:

**Directory structure:**

```
.
└── foo
    ├── __init__.py
    └── bar.py
```

**Contents of bar.py:**

```
$ cat foo/bar.py
def bat():
  print('bat')
```

**Contents of __init__.py:**

```
$ cat foo/__init__.py
from bar import bat
__all__ = [bat]
```

**Sample code and execution result:**

```
>>> import foo
>>> foo.bat
<function bat at 0x104f10140>
>>> foo.bat()
bat
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `__init__.py` TensorFlow imports `from tensorflow.python import *` which further imports `from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops`.

It then exploses all of it by doing:

```
__all__ = [s for s in dir() if s in _exported_dunders or not s.startswith('_')]
```

*Where `_exported_dunders` is a list of a few double underscored names it shouldn't expose.*

The key part is `s for s in dir()`. When calling `dir()` with no argument it shows all the names in the current module namespace. So it ends up adding all names as well as names which have been imported.